# Python: how to handle categorial values in dataset to build models

Tags: predictive-modeling, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, categorical-data, multiclass-classification

I have a training dataframe `dfTrain` and the output of `dfTrain.head()` is shown below:

```
    C0 C1                              C2   C3 C4  C5               C6  
0   1  73                 Not in universe   0   0   0  Not in universe
1   2  58  Self-employed-not incorporated   4  34   0  Not in universe
2   3  18                 Not in universe   0   0   0      High school
3   4   9                 Not in universe   0   0   0  Not in universe
4   5  10                 Not in universe   0   0   0  Not in universe
```

There are total 38 features and they are both `categorical` and `numerical`. Ignoring `C1` and scaling numerical features, I am trying to build a **Logistic Regression** model. Since, the dataframe has `categorical` features, I am creating another dataframe which has dummy variables.

```
X = pd.get_dummies(dfTrain)
```

The shape of `X` now has 160 features which is much more than that of `dfTrain`.

Then I pass `X` and `y` (where `y` is target variable) to **Logistic Regression Classifier**

```
modelLogistic = LogisticRegression(C=10**-2, class_weight = 'balanced')

modelLogistic.fit(X, y)
```

The reason to use `class_weight = 'balanced'` is that there are 17 classes in `y` and highly imbalanced.

My question is: is my approach correct? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your approach seems to be right. The only thing that I would like to point out is that while it is desirable to convert categorical features to dummies but if you don't have enough memory then you can even consider to factorize your categorical variables. You can read about it more [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html).
Also, just make sure that after converting to dummies, the number of features are reasonable compared to the number of training samples.

Comment: So if I do this conversation, I will still have to convert features into numerical values?